# What does the "Copy Source" column mean in a document library/list?

Tags: list, document-library, column

Pretty basic one here.  Google borks out.  I have a document library, and one of the columns is named "Copy Source".  What does the data in the column mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Copy Source" (internal name is "_CopySource") field contains the URL of the source document. SharePoint sets this out of the box when moving a file through the UI, though it is settable programmatically too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  So this is only populated when moving/copying a file?

Comment: Yes, to the best of my knowledge. The column is just a derivation.